# Add value to a Row by matching column name in one table to column value in another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

Df1:

```
variant ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 .... ID80000
123     0    1   2   1         0
321     1    2   1   1         1
543     1    1   2   1         1
6542    1    0   0   1         0  
243     1    0   2   1         1
654     0    1   1   2         1 
342     1    2   1   2         1
present 0    1   0   1         0
```

Df2:

```
ID  sex    yob         disease
ID1  M    10/10/1910    cancer
ID2  F     05/02/2000   CML
ID3  F     01/01/1983   gout
```

I would like to add the columns from DF2 as rows onto the DF1 putting the column names into the variant column of DF1 by matching onto IDs

Desired outcome

```
variant ID1            ID2       ID3     ID4 .... ID80000
123     0               1         2       1         0
321     1               2         1       1         1
543     1               1         2       1         1
6542    1               0         0       1         0  
243     1               0         2       1         1
654     0               1         1       2         1 
342     1               2         1       2         1
present 0               1         0       1         0
sex     M               F         F       NA        NA
yob     10/10/1910  05/02/2000 01/01/1983 NA        NA
disease cancer         CML       gout     NA        NA
```

I have tried:

```
df1["sex",] <- df2$sex[match(df2$ID, colnames(df1),]
```

Which doesn't work.

I have got this to work:

```
df1["sex",] <- ifelse(colnames(df1) %in% df2$ID, df2$sex, NA)
```

I don't even know how to approach doing this with more than one column at a time.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: could you to do ```dput(df1[1:7, 1:5])``` and ```dput(df2[1:3, 1:4])``` and share output for make your example reproducible?

Comment: I'm afraid I work within an airlocked HPC environment so can't export any data, hence the  made up table. Happy to edit the table to make it more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

Although this works for this example, you can't use it as-is for "any" other data set. It requires some knowledge of the data, which can be adjusted easily when following the preparation steps (see explanation).

```
library(data.table)

rbindlist(list(df1, cbind( variant=names(df2)[2:ncol(df2)],
  setnames( data.frame( t(df2[,2:ncol(df2)]) ), df2[,1] ))), fill=T)

    variant        ID1        ID2        ID3 ID4
 1:     123          0          1          2   1
 2:     321          1          2          1   1
 3:     543          1          1          2   1
 4:    6542          1          0          0   1
 5:     243          1          0          2   1
 6:     654          0          1          1   2
 7:     342          1          2          1   2
 8: present          0          1          0   1
 9:     sex          M          F          F  NA
10:     yob 10/10/1910 05/02/2000 01/01/1983  NA
11: disease     cancer        CML       gout  NA
```

**Explanation**

`df1` is fine but `df2` needs some care, since we do not have a *variant* column.

```
# first part of df2, all "ID" columns [2->end]
setnames( data.frame( t(df2[,2:ncol(df2)]) ), df2[,1] )
#               ID1        ID2        ID3
#sex              M          F          F
#yob     10/10/1910 05/02/2000 01/01/1983
#disease     cancer        CML       gout

# second part of df2, prepare first column
names(df2)[2:ncol(df2)]
#[1] "sex"     "yob"     "disease"

# put together with name variant
cbind( variant=names(df2)[2:ncol(df2)], 
  setnames( data.frame( t(df2[,2:ncol(df2)]) ), df2[,1] ))
#        variant        ID1        ID2        ID3
#sex         sex          M          F          F
#yob         yob 10/10/1910 05/02/2000 01/01/1983
#disease disease     cancer        CML       gout

# now df2 is ready to be matched with df1s column names using rbindlist like above
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(variant = c("123", "321", "543", "6542", "243", 
"654", "342", "present"), ID1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), ID2 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L), ID3 = c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ID4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), sex = c("M", "F", 
"F"), yob = c("10/10/1910", "05/02/2000", "01/01/1983"), disease = c("cancer", 
"CML", "gout")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Hi @Andre Wildberg. I came up with pretty much the same solution as you. So, I will not post an answer. That said, just a quick note: I suggest you use the `setnames()` function instead of `setNames()` to use the dedicated function of the `data.table` library. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery That's a nice suggestion, thanks! I'll put it in!

Comment: Sorry I was running this again and in the first line am getting "Error in setnames( data.frame( t(df2[,2:ncol(df2)]) ), df2[,1] ) : Passed a vector of type "list". Needs to be type "charachter".

Comment: @tacrolimus Tried it and it works. df2[,1] is a vector of characters, not a list. Did you add the library and define df1 and df2 from the example?

Comment: @AndreWildberg I am using my own data that whilst similar is not exactly the same. But it is in an airlock so it is hard for me to who it to you

Comment: @tacrolimus I copied df2 from your example. I assume that your df2$ID is a list. Try using `unlist(df2[,1])` instead of plain `df2[,1]` in the command.

Comment: @tacrolimus ... or use `setNames` with an upper case N. It's less picky and works fine with either.

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using dplyr for adjust df2, magrittr for pipe operator and data.table for join both df's

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df2 <- as_tibble(t(df2[, -1])) %>% 
  `colnames<-` (df2[["ID"]]) %>% 
  mutate(variant = rownames(t(df2[, -1]))) %>% 
  relocate(variant)

library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)
```